# df.na.fill is not working when columns names have special characters( . dot character)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

`df.na.fill` and `df.na.replace` are not working when the column name has `.` character.

```
val df = List((1,"name"),(2,null)).toDF("id","A.a")
df.na.fill(Map("A.a" -> "test"))
```

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot resolve column name "A.a" among (id, `A.a`);

I also tried with the ` character:

```
df.na.fill(Map("`A.a`" -> "test"))
```

obtaining the same error:

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot resolve column name
>   "`A.a`" among (id, `A.a`);

Comment: The problem is with both the backticks and the period. For example `df.select(df.columns(1))` gives the same analysis exception: `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '\`A.a\`' given input columns: [id, \`A.a\`];`

Comment: small Correction my column name is having only dot                                           
 val df = List((1,"name"),(2,null)).toDF("id","`A.a`")  , getting same analysis error